# Is there a way to "merge" two object that are inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have two arrays that i want two merge, something like this:

```
const arr1 = [{
    id: 1,
    isAvailable: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    isAvailable: true
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    isAvailable: true
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    isAvailable: false
  }
]

const arr2 = [{
    id: 1,
    isAvailable: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    isAvailable: false
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    isAvailable: false
  }
]
```

The outcome that I'm looking for is somethig like:

```
const arr3 = [{
    id: 1,
    isAvailable: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    isAvailable: false
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    isAvailable: true
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    isAvailable: false
  }
]
```

I need to update the values of the first array with the values of the second array so I can have a new array with what's truly available and what's not.

Comment: Could `arr2` contain items that do not exist in `arr1`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir no, the items in arr2 are going to be always in arr1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter `arr1` based on `arr2` and then just merge filtered `arr2` with `arr1`

```js
const arr1 = [{
  id: 1,  isAvailable: true
},
{
  id: 2,  isAvailable: true
},
{
  id: 4,  isAvailable: true
},
{
  id: 6,  isAvailable: false
}
];

const arr2 = [{
  id: 1,  isAvailable: false
},
{
  id: 2,  isAvailable: false
},
{
  id: 6,  isAvailable: false
}
];

const result = arr1.filter(a => !arr2.some(s => s.id == a.id)).concat(arr2);
console.log(result);
```

Or using `map`, `some` and `find` methods:

```js
const arr1 = [{
  id: 1, isAvailable: true
},
{
  id: 2, isAvailable: true
},
{
  id: 4, isAvailable: true
},
{
  id: 6,
  isAvailable: false
}
];

const arr2 = [{
  id: 1, isAvailable: false
},
{
  id: 2, isAvailable: false
},
{
  id: 6, isAvailable: false
}
];
const result = arr1.map(a=> arr2.some(f=> f.id == a.id) ? 
                            arr2.find(f=> f.id == a.id) : a 
                        );
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ItsMeAndrea I am really glad to help you!:)

Answer (score 2):

You could first transform `arr2` into a map object that maps the IDs to their availability, something like `{ "1": true, "4": false, ... }`. And then map `arr1` objects into a new array of objects while updating the `isAvailable` property using the map object:

```
let map = arr2.reduce((acc, o) => (acc[o.id] = o.isAvailable, acc), {});

let arr3 = arr1.map(o => ({
  id: o.id,
  isAvailable: map.hasOwnProperty(o.id) ? map[o.id] : o.isAvailable
}));
```

Each new object will have the same id as the original. Its `isAvailable` property will either be the value from the map object or its original value depending on whether or not it has an entry in the map object (whether or not it has an object in `arr2`)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sample program according to your example. Hope it solves your problem

```js
const arr1 = [{
    id: 1,
    isAvailable: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    isAvailable: true
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    isAvailable: true
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    isAvailable: true
  }
]

const arr2 = [{
    id: 1,
    isAvailable: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    isAvailable: false
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    isAvailable: false
  }
]
const arr3 = []
for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  let found = arr2.find(item => item.id === arr1[i].id)
  if (found)
    arr3.push(found)
  else
    arr3.push(arr1[i])
}
console.log(arr3)
```

Output is
    `[ { id: 1, isAvailable: false },
      { id: 2, isAvailable: false },
      { id: 4, isAvailable: true },
      { id: 6, isAvailable: false } ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Array.map()` by overwriting the value if it exists in the second array.

```
const newArray = arr1.map(({ id, isAvailable}) => {
  const matchingObjects = arr2.filter(({ id: id2 }) => id === id2);
  return matchingObjects.length > 0
    ? { id, isAvailable: matchingObjects[0].isAvailable } // replace the original value
    : { id, isAvailable } // do not overwrite this value
})
```